# mySQL - Doubles up data in join

Tags: mysql

I have an sql query that joins together several tables with LEFT JOINS. The Data retrieved from the query is doubled up.

Query;

```
SELECT 

        T.url AS track_url,
        T.name AS track_name,

        S.status,

        E.action,
        E.ID,
        E.timestamp,

        F.ID AS follower_ID,
        F.follows_ID,

        A.name,
        A.DP,
        A.url AS artist_url



      FROM events E

      LEFT JOIN 
      TRACKS T
      ON T.ID = E.ID AND E.action = 'has uploaded a track.'

      LEFT JOIN 
      STATUS S
      ON S.ID = E.ID AND E.action = 'has some news.'

      LEFT JOIN 
      ARTISTS A
      ON A.ID = E.ID


      LEFT JOIN artist_follows F
      ON F.follows_ID = E.ID


      WHERE E.ID != '2'  AND F.ID = '2'

     ORDER BY E.timestamp DESC LIMIT 5
```

Result (only data from `status` AND `events` is shown);

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| status | action        | ID | timestamp | follower_id | follows_id |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| test   | has some news.| 3  | T.1       | 4           | 3          |
| another| has some news.| 3  | T.1       | 4           | 3          |
| test   | has some news.| 3  | T.2       | 4           | 3          |
| another| has some news.| 3  | T.2       | 4           | 3          |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

As you can see the data from `status` is doubled up. `T.2` belongs to the status `another` and T.1 belongs to the status `test`. What is shown is that the data from `status` is shown twice, once with `T.1's` set of data from `events` and once with `T.2's` set of data from `events`. This means that when an ID has posted more than one status, the status is joined with every bit of data from that ID in the events table.

Comment: can you post the schema of your tables with the records?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not at my regular computer so I can't test it, but shouldn't you replace `AND` with `WHERE` on your joins?

Comment: There are no ands in the joins. The and is in the where clause after all the joins

Comment: Nope it seems like the `AND` is fine. Using a `WHERE` gives an sql error